# How to create new tack with atachments in Jira use Java?

Tags: java, jira

I want to create new task with attachments in Jira. So I try:

```
BasicCredentials creds = new BasicCredentials("username", "password");
JiraClient jira = new JiraClient("https://url", creds);
    try {
        File file1 = new File("D:\\image1.jpg");
        File file2 = new File("D:\\description.pdf");
        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
        fileList.add(file1);
        fileList.add(file2);

        Issue newIssue = jira.createIssue("ProjectName", "Task")
                .field(Field.SUMMARY, "Task with attachments")
                .field(Field.DESCRIPTION, "Description for task with attachments.")
                .field(Field.PRIORITY, Field.valueById("2"))
                .field(Field.ATTACHMENT, fileList)
                .execute();
    } catch (JiraException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this way is wrong. How to include `fileList` to Jira task?

Comment: What is JiraClient? I do not see it in JIRA API: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/

Comment: @VolodymyrKrupach JiraClient https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client

Comment: You better contact author of the API.
On the github page there is a sample where I see:

/* Add an attachment */
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\screenshot.jpg");
            issue.addAttachment(file);

and after you probably need to invoke update method.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution:

```
BasicCredentials creds = new BasicCredentials("username", "password");
JiraClient jira = new JiraClient("https://url", creds);
try {
    File file1 = new File("D:\\image1.jpg");
    File file2 = new File("D:\\description.pdf");
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    fileList.add(file1);
    fileList.add(file2);

    Issue newIssue = jira.createIssue("ProjectName", "Task")
            .field(Field.SUMMARY, "Task with attachments")
            .field(Field.DESCRIPTION, "Description for task with attachments.")
            .field(Field.PRIORITY, Field.valueById("2"))
            .execute();
    newIssue.addAttachment(file1);
    newIssue.addAttachment(file2);
} catch (JiraException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```